# Grid-column-end with items that have a fixed width not aligning

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have an item that needs to have a fixed width, but when I try and right-align it to a certain column, it overflows. Removing the width fixes the problem, but that's unfortunately not a solution I can use.

Using `grid-column` to set the width works, but I want to have greater control over the size of the item, if possible.

I also tried making the container span grids 1/4 and then aligned content inside of it, but I'm getting something wrong because that doesn't quite work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  align-content: start;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 
  height: 8rem;

  background-color: white;
}

.section-1 {
    grid-column: 1/4;
}
.section-2 {
  grid-column: 1/4;
}
.section-3 {
  grid-column: 4/6;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.controls {
  width: 9rem;
  height: 3rem;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section section-1">Section 1</div>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="control-btn"></div>
    <div class="control-btn"></div>
    <div class="control-btn"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section section-2">Section 2</div>
  <div class="section section-3">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

[image: Grid alignment problem]

[CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/XWEjepV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `justify-self: end;` to that item but you can get overflow on the left side

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  align-content: start;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 
  height: 8rem;

  background-color: white;
}

.section-1 {
    grid-column: 1/4;
}
.section-2 {
  grid-column: 1/4;
}
.section-3 {
  grid-column: 4/6;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.controls {
  width: 9rem;
  height: 3rem;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  background-color: white;
  justify-self:end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section section-1">Section 1</div>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="control-btn"></div>
    <div class="control-btn"></div>
    <div class="control-btn"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section section-2">Section 2</div>
  <div class="section section-3">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Do you know why it was behaving like that? Just seems a bit odd. Overflow left isn't a big deal - it's going to happen somewhere at some point!

Comment: it's not odd, the default direction is left to right so the item will get placed at the beginning of the column and overflow to the right. You either change the direction or the alignment

Comment: I meant odd to me. Which column was it being placed at the beginning of?

Comment: @NickW the 4th column like you indicated

Comment: By using `grid-column-end`? It also doesn't look like it's starting on column 4 either, more like 3?

Comment: @NickW yes it's the 3rd column. column-end specify the end line which is 4 so the item will get placed between line 3 and line 4 so column 3